# ASP MVC routing issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a few situations with my routing I guess. I am trying to use a Url.Action for this, but it is not working as I hoped. Probably something small I just miss?

I am sitting on `http://localhost:63061/service`, inside the UI there is a button. Once I click on that I want it to bring me to `http://localhost:63061/partdispatch`

Seems quite simple right? but for some reason I just keep having the wrongs routes.

```
onclick="window.location.href = '@Url.Action("PartDispatch", "mainmenu")';"
```

routing settings:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "MainMenu", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Comment: So you are calling Index method of partdispatch Controller Right ??

Comment: I want to go to the localhost/partdispatch yes.

Comment: @BasantaMatia mention this in an answer I will vote you as answer.  Really simple.

Comment: Happy to know that You solved that and learned :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do,

```
onclick="window.location = "../PartDispatch/Index";"
```

Or-else

```
onclick="window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "PartDispatch")';"
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Basanta Matia mentioned very simple whatever I wish to do. Calling the index. so I changed the action.url to `'@Url.Action("index", "partdispatch")'`and that was the only thing I had to do. quite ashamed. Really need to learn this:
https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=url.action+documentation&*